# moov atom not found (Extracting unique faces from youtube video)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, ffmpeg, urllib

I got the error below

```
Saved 0 unique faces
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000024f505224c0] moov atom not found
```

Trying to extract unique faces from a YouTube video with the code below which is designed to download the YouTube video and extract unique faces into a folder named faces. I got an empty video and folder. Please do check the Python code below

```
import os
import urllib.request
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np

# Step 1: Download the YouTube video
video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JriaiYZZhbY&t=4s"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(video_url, "video.mp4")

# Step 2: Extract frames from the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
frames = []
for i in range(frame_count):
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, i)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frames.append(frame)
cap.release()

# Step 3: Detect faces in the frames
detected_faces = []
for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)
    for j, location in enumerate(face_locations):
        top, right, bottom, left = location
        face_image = frame[top:bottom, left:right]
        cv2.imwrite(f"detected_{i}_{j}.jpg", face_image)
        detected_faces.append(face_image)

# Step 4: Save the faces as separate images
if not os.path.exists("faces"):
    os.makedirs("faces")
known_faces = []
for i in range(len(detected_faces)):
    face_image = detected_faces[i]
    face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image)[0]
    known_faces.append(face_encoding)
    cv2.imwrite(f"faces/face_{i}.jpg", face_image)
print("Saved", len(known_faces), "unique faces")
```

Comment: your file is corrupted or not an mp4/mov file. it's a ***web page***. you can't just download a youtube page like that and expect it to be a file. please review [mre]. MRE implies that you provide the necessary input data.

Comment: Can you explain better?... If this is downloading the entire webpage, how do I not download the entire webpage and download only the video?

Comment: that's a different question though... what did you find in your research?

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not an mp4/mov file.

***It's a web page, not a video file.***

You can't just download a YouTube *web page* like that and expect to receive a video file.